# Set range in formula via a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, excel-indirect

Is there a way to set the range of a formula by reference to another cell's content? I need the formula to be dynamic based on what I key. For example, I need the formula: `Sum(A1:B10)`, is there a way to do this:

> =Sum("RefrenceCellC1" : "RefrenceCellC2")

(where C1 = `A1` and C2 = `B10`), so if I change cell C2 content to `B20` the formula then becomes: `Sum(A1:B20)`?

Comment: Have a look at the `INDIRECT` function http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/indirect-HP005209139.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of an answer (as alluded to by @tigeravatar):

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(C1&":"&C2))
```